# Adding custom geometry to the viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I have a model that I wish to subdivide, by drawing semi-transparent boxes over different parts.

Following the example https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/02/custom-transparent-meshes-with-view-data-api.html I have drawn the boxes and added them to the sceneAfter object.  So they draw semi-transparently, and the model appears within them as expected.

I have used a bufferGeometry, which avoids the missing attributes error.

However, I cannot either select the boxes, or ignore the boxes and select the components inside them.  The example states "Another option would be to create the custom geometry the same way the viewer does, so it could participate in the selection".  Is there any documentation on how the viewer creates the geometry?

Searching through the source, I can see `dbId` and `fragId` being assigned to a `Mesh` in `addSingleMesh`, but as part of the model consolidation.

I am not yet sure if I want to select the boxes or the items within them, but as the viewer knows to ignore components that are ghosted out, I hope this is a relatively simple thing to toggle?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a custom mesh to the scene it will not take part to the viewer selection mechanism. As far as I know we don't have a sample that illustrates how to achieve that, so I'm asking to the development team if they can provide some directions...

In the meantime you can add some logic to handle the selection of the meshes that you added separately. This is what I did in the sample referenced by that blog post: [Boolean Operations in the Forge Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/boolean-operations-forge-viewer). Custom selection is performed [there](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/blob/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.WallAnalyzer/Viewing.Extension.WallAnalyzer.js#L766):

```
onClick (event) {

  const pointer = event.pointers
    ? event.pointers[0]
    : event

  const rayCaster = this.pointerToRaycaster(
    this.viewer.impl.canvas,
    this.viewer.impl.camera,
    pointer)

  const intersectResults = rayCaster.intersectObjects(
    this.intersectMeshes, true)

  if (intersectResults.length) {

    const mesh = intersectResults[0].object

    this.panel.setVisible(false)

    this.panel.setNodeProperties(mesh.dbId)

    this.panel.setVisible(true)
  }
}
```

You may also be interested in that article which deals with filtering the viewer native selection: [Controlling components selection in the Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/controlling-components-selection-viewer).

Hope that helps

Comment: This lets me select the boxes, after I added a `ToolInterface` to get the `handleSingleClick` event.  So half way there.

Comment: Still trying to select the item under the box.  It appears that `Viewer3DImpl.rayIntersect` is selecting the item, and then it looks at `sceneAfter` and finds the box.  So if there is a safe way to add `dbId` or `fragId` values to my custom mesh, I think that rayIntersect will find the box through the normal selection without needing this.

Comment: And the other request would be for a flag that I can add to the children of `sceneAfter` to skip them in the `intersectObject`, or filter them from the results before it drops all the intersections with higher distance values.

Comment: `mesh.dbId = dbId` looks safe enough to me, or am I misunderstanding the question?